# Bidirectional Bubble sort c#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting

I have a homework assignment of coding a bidirectional bubble sort. Can someone please see if my logic is correct with respect to it. I Don't want code as I want to figure it out myself. I just want a logic check of how i understand it.

As i understand the Bidirectional Bubble sort you implement 2 for loops one starting at position 1 in the list and performing a normal bubble sort. As the first for loop reaches the end a second one is implemented working in reverse. I just don't completely understand what the terminating conditions for each loop would be.

Would the for loop conditions be something as follows?

loop 1 - `for(i = 0; i < Count -i; i++)`

loop 2 - `for(j = Count - i; j > i; j--)`

in each loop the swap conditions would be specified.

Thanks

Comment: Awesome sort video : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SJwEwA5gOkM

Comment: This is probably more of a http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ or http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ question.

Comment: @TiesonT. Although "programmers" would be an OK fit, "codereview" requires a complete, working, piece of code authored by the OP.

Comment: Im pretty new too this website so any help with respect to which tags and where to post questions like this would be appreciated

Comment: @user2046257 http://stackoverflow.com/faq answers most questions. Someone will generally tell you when you're "breaking the rules."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "classic" bubble sort goes through the entire array on each iteration, so the loops should be

```
for(i = 0; i < Count - 1; i++)
```

and

```
for(j = Count - 1; j > 0; j--)
```

Both loops skip one index: the first loop skips the last index, while the second loop skips the initial one. This is so that your code could safely compare `data[i]` to `data[i+1]`, and `data[j]` to `data[j-1]`.

**EDIT** The ["optimized"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort#Optimizing_bubble_sort) bubble sort skips the initial `k` elements on `k`-th iteration. Since your bubble sort is bidirectional, you will be able to skip the initial `k` and the tail `k` elements, like this:

```
 int k = 0;
 do { // The outer loop
     ...
     for(int i = k; i < Count - k - 1; i++)
         ...
     for(int j = Count - k - 1; j > k ; j--)
         ...
     k++;
} while (<there were swaps>);
```

Comment: So the reverse iteration is not dependent on where the first loop was? it always goes to position 1 even though loop 1 checked those already?

Comment: @user2046257 Correct, because the first loop may have moved elements in the part of the array that it checked. That's part of the reason behind bubble sort's inefficiency.

Comment: Technically after the first passes (i.e. up and down) then you no longer need to check the first or last element since they are known to be the lowest and highest elements. So, i doesn't always need to start at 0 and j doesn't always need to end at 0.

Comment: @Xantix That's the "optimized" bubble sort. It does look from the question that it's what the OP is trying to do, so I edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help guys. Really appreciate it. It helped a lot with my coding.

Answer (score 2):

bidirectional bubble sort works like this:

instead of passing the list from bottom to top every time (bubble sort) you start **one time at the bottom** and **every second time from the top** of the list.

the wikipedia article does a way better job at explaining it:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cocktail_sort

- rich